# Laravel belongsTo not returning any values

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I have a class called Dbc which has 'links' attached to it called DbcLink.
Each link had a 'type' (DbcLinkType)

I'm returning the links attached to the Dbc fine

```
 class Dbc extends Model
   {
    use HasFactory;

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    public function links($filter = NULL)
    {
        return $this->hasMany(DBCLink::class);
    }
   }
```

---

```
$social = $dbc->links()->first();
dd($social);
```

[image]

but when I try and get the 'link type from those links it returns an empty list

```
class DbcLink extends Model
 {
    use HasFactory;

    public function dbc()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Dbc::class);
    }

    public function link_type()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(DbcLinkType::class);
    }
 }
```

---

```
$social = $dbc->links()->first();
dd($social->link_type()->get());
```

[image]

dbc_links table

[image]

dbc_link_types table

[image]

Any suggestions as to why its returning an empty list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When invoking the link_type method, Eloquent will attempt to find a `DbcLinkType` model that has an `id` which matches the `link_type_id` column on the `DbcLink` model.

> Eloquent determines the foreign key name by examining the name of the relationship method and suffixing the method name with _id.
> [1](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one-defining-the-inverse-of-the-relationship)

Rename your relation method from `link_type` to `dbc_link_type` so that it looks up `dbc_link_type_id` column on the `DbcLink` model.

Alternately, you can inform Eloquent to find the `DbcLinkType` model that has an `id` which matches the `dbc_link_type_id` column on the `DbcLink` model.

You can accomplish that by specifying the foreignKey when defining the relation;

```php
        return $this->belongsTo(DbcLinkType::class, 'dbc_link_type_id');
```

Answer (score 1):

You should specify your "Foreign and owner keys" like this:

```
 public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(TableName::class, 'foreign_key', 'owner_key');
}
```